# What is the state-of-the-art for solving polynomials systems over fields that are not algebraically closed?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, polynomials, arithmetic-geometry, fields

I am not working in the field of algorithmic algebraic geometry - yet, for my current work, I need some results from it.

More specifically, what is the state-of-the-art when it comes to solving (whatever "solving" means in this case) system of polynomials of fields that are not algebraically closed, whose ideal has dimension $>0$?
Could you recommend a survey paper that summarizes what has been achieved so far?

For the case of $0$-dimensional ideals, there seems to exist many heavily cited papers, like "Solving Zero-dimensional Algebraic Systems" by D. Lazard, which seem mostly to be concerned with finding ways of to display the system of polynomials in a nice way (e.g. triangularly). Are these articles already superseded, or does it make sense to read them?

**Edit:** In particular, I'm interested in the field $\mathbb{R}$, since most of my example will come from here (but $\mathbb{Q}$ might be also useful; and perhaps even the ring $\mathbb{Z}$; I don't yet know where the results I will get for $\mathbb{R}$ will take me).
Also worth making more precise: In the case of positive dimension of the ideal, I'm interested in methods that tell me, if I project to whole, infinite solution space down to a single variable and I'm interested in, in what set this variable lies. More formally, if $V(f_1,\ldots,f_s)\subseteq F^n$  is my solution variety, with $f_i \in F[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, and I'm interested in some specific variable, say $n_0$, what methods are there that describe $\mathop{\rm proj}_{n_0}(V(f_1,\ldots,f_s))$?

Comment: This question is way too broad to give any kind of meaningful answer. If you can be more specific about how this question is relevant to your work, that should help to give the question more focus.

Comment: In particular, "solving" might be interpreted in various communities as either finding a single solution or finding all solutions. This gets murkier for positive-dimensional solution sets: how should one represent "all solutions"?

Comment: @RP_ hm... I don't think it would be that helpful to describe how solving polynomial systems arise in my work, since there are no restrictions on the structure of polynomials systems, so I'm still left with the "how can I solve general polynomials systems over the reals". more specifically, I'm investigating certain classes of neural nets and some metric properties of them, that lead to the questions whether some polynomial systems have solutions.

Comment: That is not what you asked: you asked about "fields that are not algebraically closed." Now it turns out you are only interested in the reals. Better edit your question.

Comment: @RP_ Well, I'm not exclusively interested in the reals, but it does consist in the most important case - see my edit.

Comment: @tim  yes, that is indeed problem in positive dimension. I'm looking for any kind of parametrization of solutions that help my isolate specific variables, as mentioned in my edit.

Comment: To give you an idea of the difficulty, deciding whether a plane curve $P(x,y)=0$ with $P \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ has a real point or not, is a non-trivial task in general, you need the notion of cylindrical decomposition from real algebraic geometry. Yet this existence problem and many more from algebraic geometry can be solved and have even been implemented -- see the softwares Qepcad and Redlog. In particular, it's possible to determine whether an arbitrary system of polynomial equations in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ has a solution in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or not.

Comment: Do the polynomials of your system have exact coefficients (i.e., algebraic numbers) or are they approximations?

Comment: You can also compute projections using the softwares mentioned above. But you need exact coefficients (e.g. integers). And the output will be a boolean combination of polynomial inequalities in 1 variable.

Comment: These problems are [hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_theory_of_the_reals). If there isn't any structure to exploit, you will run out luck quickly.

Comment: @user43263 In general it's better to know things. It sounds like you already know the "dimension" is greater than zero. Do you mean dimension over the reals? I would interpret "structure" pretty broadly. Methods like CAD, Groebner Bases, resultants, and homotopy continuation have different capabilities and may outperform each other in various regimes. One should not expect a "best method" due to computational complexity, as alluded to in my previous remark. Your opportunities for success are slim for very large problems -- but you might only need a local method like Newton iteration anyway.

Comment: The equation over the quaternions $z^2 = q$ for arbitrary fixed $q \in \mathbb H$ is in a sense unsolvable. See here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342041/is-it-possible-to-constructively-prove-that-every-quaternion-has-a-square-root

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault That sounds actually very interesting to me, thank you for pointing that out. In case you are interested, as I learned through this question that the theory is more involved, I wrote a follow-up question, that details my problem more precisely:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361642/existance-of-solutions-of-polynomials-systems-and-their-rough-shape-over-m

Comment: @tim I think I might have some hope to tackle this - perhaps asking for the state-of-the art was too much. I outlined as best as I could the structure my problem has in a follow-up question (to which I linked in the comment above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the reals, I particularly like the book by Sturmfels mentioned by Alexandre Eremenko. For the rational numbers, you can hardly do better than Bjorn Poonen's book *Rational Points on Varieties*, which is available for browsing via [his homepage](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/).

For dimension $1$ specifically, Poonen also has a set of [lecture notes on rational points on curves](https://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/curves.pdf), although I always have trouble finding it. Moreover he has several expository articles (listed as such on his page) dealing with rational points on curves.

Restricted to the case of the field of rational numbers and dimension $1$ alone, this is a huge question. Restricting only to the field of rational numbers makes it even huger. Dropping any restrictions on the field entirely makes it well-nigh impossible to answer in full geberality...

Comment: It might be good to highlight the difference that, for the reals, the existence of an algorithm has been known for a long time, since work (I think) of Tarski, and it's "just" a question of improving the speed to be practical. For the rationals, the problem is completely open even in some of the simplest cases and one can easily organize multiple large conferences on non-overlapping aspects of the problem.

Comment: @WillSawin Yes absolutely, I kind of assumed that had already been mentioned somewhere...

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of Poonen's book. After doing some reading I realized, given how comprehensive the theory is, that it is absolutely necessary to outline my problem in as much detail as possible. I have written a follow-uip question in that regard (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361642/existance-of-solutions-of-polynomials-systems-and-their-rough-shape-over-m ) , since giving all that detail it seemed outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @WillSawin Just for fun, could you link one paper (perhaps a survey paper, if there is one) that describes some unknown things in case of the rationals?

Comment: @user43263 Here is a list of open problems concerning K3 surfaces, which are sometimes advertised as being the frontier of rational points research in dimension $2$: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~bviray/openproblems.pdf Although this is an arguable point, since there are plenty of questions left about rational surfaces and generally about surfaces of Kodaira dimension $-1$.

Answer (score 5):

For the real field:

**MR2830310**
Sottile, Frank
*Real solutions to equations from geometry*.
University Lecture Series, 57. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2011.

**MR2275625** Mikhalkin, Grigory *Tropical geometry and its applications*. International Congress of Mathematicians. Vol. II, 827–852, Eur. Math. Soc., Zürich, 2006.

**MR1108621** 
Khovanskiĭ, A. G.
*Fewnomials*.
American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1991.

**MR1659509** Bochnak, Jacek; Coste, Michel; Roy, Marie-Françoise *Real algebraic geometry*. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1998.

For other fields:

**MR2247966** 
Vakil, Ravi
*Schubert induction*. 
Ann. of Math. (2) 164 (2006), no. 2, 489–512.

Also:

**MR1925796** 
Sturmfels, Bernd
*Solving systems of polynomial equations*. 
CBMS Regional Conference Series in Mathematics, 97. Published for the Conference Board of the Mathematical Sciences, Washington, DC; by the American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2002.

where the real field is also discussed.

Comment: Thank you very much for all these references, in particular Sturmfels' book seems to contain useful theorems for me.